# Combining random forest model with different classes

Tags: class, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have two random forest models:
RF1 -  trains 3 classes using data from a certain time period
RF2 - trains 20 classes using data from another time period

I want to combine these two models so that three classes get predicted from the first one and the other from the second one.

Is this possible to do?

I tried adding the estimators, but that creates 500 trees for 3 classes and 500 for the rest 20 and this might create a bias when using the model.